# ubuntu 18.04 Black screen after login

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, ubuntu-gnome, nvidia-geforce

In ubuntu 18.04 after discovering that the wrong nvidia driver was polluting my kernel.log I've tried different combination of nvidia drivers with no success.

When I `sudo service gdm start` the login screen shows up but after login a black page blocks everithing,

```
4.15.0-33-generic

nvidia-340:
  Installed: 340.106-0ubuntu3
  Candidate: 340.107-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
  Version table:
     340.107-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 340.106-0ubuntu3 500
        500 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt bionic/restricted amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

How can i diagnose/solve this?

UPDATE:

Same problem with a fresh install after installing nvidia recomended drivers.
Resolved avoiding nvidia drivers.

Should this be a hardware error?

Btw video card runs with no problem in Windows.

Comment: I found a suitable solution for this issue (ubuntu 19.10) at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189993/verifying-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-19-10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem with both Ubuntu 18.10 and 19.04.  I have a dell Vostro 3670 (see https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=0f87997cd1).  This solution did not work for me. After reboot the screen stays blanc.  I found a solution to restore the Ubuntu desktop at least.  From  #17 on [proprietary drivers not showing up - Page 2](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2411777&page=2)

> I found several proposed solutions for this issue to install the
>   Nvidia drivers. None of them work for me. I found 2 methods that
>   enable you to recover the Desktop environment when this happens:
>
> First by Fossfreedom at -
>   https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/nvidia-390-black-screen/97/14
>
> You have to do a safe boot and go to root, then:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*
> sudo apt install nvidia-prime
> sudo prime-select intel
> ```
>
> Then reboot.
>
> Second form sgian entry #3 at
>   https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399985
>
> Also do a safe boot and go to root. Then:
>
> ```
> sudo apt purge nvidia*
> sudo apt install --reinstall xorg xserver-xorg-core
> ```
>
> Then reboot.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu  19.10 recently on the same box.  Got a method to install Nvidia drivers from https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-linux  It gives the same issue.  Black screen when you reboot.

Comment: I found a suitable solution for Ubuntu 19.10 at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189993/verifying-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-19-10

Answer (score 2):

I tried countless solutions that were posted on the internet, and the one single thing that worked for me was to:

- backup `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.old`
- similarly backup `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory, if it exists
- and then `cp -r /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d /etc/X11/`

I think that the `xorg.conf` file generated by `nvidia-xconfig` somehow prevents the login screen from loading.

EDIT:

Before doing the above, I did a few rounds of:

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia*'
```

```
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

(driver version may vary depending on the GPU)

See Gert Kruger's answer for more details.