# Ubuntu 18.10: Installing nvidia drivers leads to black screen after GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10 without any errors. When I restarted, I got a black screen with a blinking cursor (couldn't type anything) right after GRUB. Pressing Ctrl-Alt-F2 got me to a terminal session.

I rebooted, then tried editing GRUB by pressing `e` and changing `quiet splash` to `nomodeset`.  Pressed F10. It didn't work.

I had to reboot, press Ctrl-Alt-F2 then remove the nvidia drivers by typing `sudo apt-get purge ^nvidia`. Only then was Ubuntu able to boot successfully.

I installed the nvidia 340.107 drivers from the Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates. Rebooting got me to the same black screen as before, and I had to purge the nvidia drivers again.

System: AMD FX-6300 CPU, Asrock 970 Extreme mobo, 8 GB RAM, Nvidia GeForce 9600GT.

Thank you.

Comment: @N0rbert Being able to wake my PC up from Suspend successfully, which 18.10 can do when using the open source video driver. Nothing I tried solved the suspend problem in 18.04. Also, "5 years without problems"? Haha!

Comment: Why was the question downvoted, besides someone disagreeing with my reasons to upgrade? If there's something wrong or unclear in my question, point it out in a comment...

Comment: This helped me solve the black screen on login: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068848/ubuntu-18-04-black-screen-after-login/1145157#1145157

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had this issue too with the nvidia drivers and Ubuntu 18.10. I found a thread on the French Ubuntu website which helped me. It's a fix for Ubuntu 17.10 but it worked for me on 18.10.

Try this:

1. Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
   ```
2. Here uncomment the line

   ```
   #WaylandEnable=false
   ```

   which becomes also

   ```
   WaylandEnable=false
   ```

   Don't forget to save!

With this you should be able to install the nvidia drivers (I'm using the 390 version which works for me).

[Source](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/problemes_nvidia#session_graphique_qui_reste_noire_sous_ubuntu_1710)

Comment: I had to use `sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` (your answer was without `sudo`) and it worked! Merci beaucoup! :-)

Comment: Oh how stupid I am ! I forgot it, well seen!

Comment: @MoussierElPatate  When starting graphic apps like gedit from the terminal command line, you should use `sudo -H`, or you'll probably create a login loop problem.

Comment: @glottis When starting graphic apps like gedit from the terminal command line, you should use sudo -H, or you'll probably create a login loop problem.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Just saved my bacon too on upgrade from 18.04.

Comment: using `gedit` when being in terminal already is not a good idea and not a good advice anyway. and mentioning `sudo` doesn't seem like something that should be expected to be given - i find it pretty obvious that you need to edit config files in etc with root privileges.

Comment: You are my hero Moussier!

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968365/ubuntu-17-10-nvidia-drivers-black-screen-loop) thread helped me with the same problem (Ubuntu 18.04 GTX1080)

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

for low latency kernel headers then add

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1"
```

to your grub. Then you need to regenerate the initramfs and the Kernel modules. Dont forget to update your grub.`sudo update-grub2`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know how to do any of this.  Add to my grub?  Where?  How do I regenerate the initramfs and kernel modules?

Comment: I should add that I suspect a GRUB issue because when I updated it asked me some question about which version of some GRUB file I wanted to use.  Having no clue I asked it to show me a diff, but it continued along with the install and never showed me anything!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after upgrading from 18.04.  I have a nvidia 1070ti GPU and was previously using the `nvidia-390` driver successfully with 18.04.  For me, the upgrade (somehow) completed but left several packages partially installed i.e. I noticed several in `iu` state (not `ii` as expected) by doing this

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

I finished the install by doing this

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo reboot
```

which fixed the issue. Now, everything is fine.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried this by installing the nvidia drivers again. The `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` command showed everything as `ii`.  Rebooted, black screen again, Alt-Ctrl-F2 and tried the command again, everything is `ii`. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Sorry it didn't help you.  I should have mentioned that I had several other packages that were partially installed, not just the nvidia packages.  Which is why I did `dpkg --configure -a`, and not just an nvidia reinstall.  I'm guessing that in my case the upgrade actually partially failed, even though it completed.  Sounds like my case was a little different than yours.  Best of luck!