# Ubuntu 18.10 does not start with Nvidia drivers

Tags: boot, nvidia, xorg, pyqt, spyder

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10 from Ubuntu 18.04. I have two problems but I think they're related. I have a NVIDIA graphics card.

Problem 1: if I have the original NVIDIA graphics card drivers, then my Ubuntu doesn't boot. It stops at the boot screen. I read on some online forums to do CTRL + ALT + F2 and uninstall Nvidia drivers. Then boot into Ubuntu and reinstall Nvidia drivers. However, if I reinstall the drivers, my Ubuntu doesn't boot again.

Problem 2: While using Spyder through Anaconda and Python 3.6, I get the following messages on my terminal --

```
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch5: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 1 relocs 0
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000000 00000002 00000004 00000004 00000000
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch5: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 2 relocs 0
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000000 00000002 00000004 00000004 00000000
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000001 00000006 00000004 00000000 00000004
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch5: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 1 relocs 0
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000000 00000003 00000004 00000004 00000000
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch5: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 1 relocs 0
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000000 00000003 00000004 00000004 00000000
python: ../nouveau/pushbuf.c:723: nouveau_pushbuf_data: Assertion `kref' failed.
```

After a while, Spyder crashes. I read on online forums that this is a problem related to PyQt and NVIDIA drivers. I need to use updated PyQt and NVIDIA drivers. However, I already have PyQt 5.9 installed and I can't install the NVIDIA drivers because then I won't be able to boot.

Checking for Ubuntu drivers gives me --

```
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GT218 [GeForce 210]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

To install the NVIDIA drivers I use,

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Can someone please help? I need to use Spyder.

Comment: You might want to add how you install multiple Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I did that. Why did I get a -1 on the question?

Comment: Welcome to the SE network! Please update your question to be very clear on what you're asking, as while you've provided great information, it's not clear at present; are you asking how to install Nvidia drivers? why Ubuntu doesn't have what you need by default?..

Answer (score 3):

Why do people troll so much? What he's asking IS clear. His pc doesn't boot with Nvidia cards and he's wondering how to get it to boot with those cards. Stackoverflow and askUbuntu have so many people who thumbs down for no reason it's upsetting.

Unfortunately, I have the same problem you have. Don't know why it's happening. I upgraded from 18.04 to see if it'd help my hdmi sound work but it didn't. Now I have this Nvidia graphics card issue. If anyone has a solution help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
The answer from MoussierElPatate on this link worked like a charm.
[Ubuntu 18.10: Installing nvidia drivers leads to black screen after GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085042/ubuntu-18-10-installing-nvidia-drivers-leads-to-black-screen-after-grub)

Answer (score 0):

It helped me:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

```
sudo apt-get update
ubuntu-drivers devices
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```