# gdm3 won't start by default after upgrade to 18.10 from 18.04

Tags: boot, login, lightdm, gdm, 18.10

When I configure gdm as my default display manager (`dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`) and then reboot, I get a black screen with a blinking cursor. From there, I cannot do anything since the ttys does not work (ctrl+alt+F1 to F7). I could not figure out why.

In order to resolve this issue, I boot into safe mode, reconfigure lightdm and then reboot.

I observed that gdm could not start for some reason (hence the black screen).

```
$ systemctl status gdm.service 
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Nov 04 16:46:05 rigel systemd[1]: gdm.service: Unit cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
```

When I manually start gdm `systemctl status gdm.service` I am able to logout and log back in using gdm. After reboot, the black screen occurs again with the blinking cursor.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
GNOME Shell 3.30.1
Ubuntu 18.10 cosmic
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.18.0-10-generic
NVIDIA driver 410.73 (GeForce GTX 970)
```

Comment: How old is this computer? Laptop or desktop? Video card? Does it boot if you set nomodeset in the kernel boot line in GRUB?

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the suggestion. The computer is a desktop (not old, about 3 years). My video card is Nvidia GeForce GTX 970. I tried the `nomodeset` flag in GRUB but I got the same error.

Comment: You could try reinstalling gdm3. Maybe the update didn't complete. `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm3`. Then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and reboot.

Comment: I have also tried that, did not work.

Comment: Update: Disabling `Wayland` and reinstalling `ubuntu-session` fixed the issue, as @adrinux suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem on both my Ubuntu 18.04 boxes after upgrade to 18.10. Both are configured with nvidia grahpics and to use the vanilla gnome session Ubuntu provides (not the Unity-ish version they munged together). Much faffing with nvidia drivers had no effect.

I did two other things - not sure which brought it back. From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1087050/848856)
Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` as a `sudo` and uncomment the line to force Xorg over Wayland

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

I also installed `ubuntu-session`:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-session
```

But not sure whether that is really required so I suggest you try editing `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and rebooting first.

hth

Comment: Thanks!! I have tried to disable Wayland `WaylandEnable=false` (I saw it in the same answer as you), but it had not worked. However, reinstalling `ubuntu-session` fixed the problem.

Comment: Out if interest did you revert that change to `WaylandEnable=false` before reinstalling `ubuntu-session`?

Comment: Yes, I first disabled `Wayland` and then reinstalled `ubuntu-session`.

Comment: For me reinstalling ubuntu-session worked. No need to disable wayland. The problem started after upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04.

Comment: Installing ubuntu-session worked for me too! Thanks for the help!