# 18.04 not booting into Gnome GUI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, nvidia, gnome

For some reason my clean installed 18.04.01 will not boot to home screen.
I get a huge list (looking like responses from a terminal) finishing in:

```
[  OK  ]  Started GNOME Display Manager.
```

I left this overnight and the screen was unchanged - still with that huge list.
I then tried installing another version of 18.04.01 alongside my existing - exactly the same is happening.
Help please as I have no computer.
As an aside - could NVIDIA graphics be causing this? I tried updating the driver just before this happened.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089970/gdm3-wont-start-by-default-after-upgrade-to-18-10-from-18-04/1096445#1096445) when I upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10. `gdm` failed to start.

In order to be sure that the problem is with gdm, try booting in safe-mode [(see here how)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-ubuntu-in-safe-mode), drop a root terminal and type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. Then reboot and check if it boots correctly. If yes, you can try the solution offered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089970/gdm3-wont-start-by-default-after-upgrade-to-18-10-from-18-04/1096445#1096445) for a similar problem by disabling `Wayland` and reinstalling `ubuntu-session`.