# After Windows Update, Ubuntu second screen not detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Ubuntu worked fine before Windows update on my SSD. Kernel settings reseted for some reason.I readjusted BIOS, I enabled PCI 1 instead of motherboard setting. 1 hdmi and 1 dvi cable is connected to GTX 970. 
I had 390.116 nvidia driver on Ubuntu. (But maybe I had an older driver and I updated it with sudo update before I used Windows, and that new update caused problems.)

**What happends during the boot:**

Second screen shows up during boot, I select Ubuntu on boot menu and then some boot stuff happen and then second screen gets disabled and first screen shows up instead, and i login and continue.

From Settings->Display recognizes only the first screen.
Nvidia X Server Settings -> X Server Display Configuration -> Only the first screen is detected.

**What I have tried:**

By using tty --> I purged nvidia-* --> rebooted --> worked like charm! the problem is with nvidia drivers (And I need them for gpu accelerated processing stuff).

From Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers --> Couple of nvidia drivers show up (390,396,410,415,418) I purged and reinstalled 4 of them and none of them worked.

Can the problem related with GNOME?

Comment: After messing up with the system, I had no choice but installing 18.10.
I installed nvidia 390 driver on it and failed on boot stage.
However, the answer in this page helped me solve the problem.
If anyone has this issue must try deleting the hash from "#WaylandEnable=false
" in this file:
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085042/ubuntu-18-10-installing-nvidia-drivers-leads-to-black-screen-after-grub/1087050#comment1874892_1087050

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in 2019 on my HP Omen laptop. After a pushed-windows update, my bios got updated. After that my ubuntu boot-up time increased and my second monitor was no longer being detected. The solution was to disable secure boot in the bios.