# Nvidia drivers causes Ubuntu 19.04 to hang after GRUB startup

Tags: drivers, grub2, nvidia, 19.04

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04. For some reason the NVIDIA drivers break the startup completely, I have tried every single method that had been suggested, from editing the GRUB during startup to include 'nomodeset' to disabling nouveau. The closest I came to it working was adding 'nvidia-drm.modeset=1', which finally reached the login screen, but even that hang when I logged in. When I boot into recovery mode and purge the NVIDIA drivers, I can get in again no problem. How should I proceed to have the drivers installed, because at this point any whiff of NVIDIA being installed results in hanging.

Answer (score 0):

After spending most of the day rebooting editing GRUB and reinstalling NVIDIA many times, I found an answer that worked for Ubuntu 18.10, solution found at [Ubuntu 18.10: Installing nvidia drivers leads to black screen after GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085042/ubuntu-18-10-installing-nvidia-drivers-leads-to-black-screen-after-grub?rq=1).