# Ubuntu 18.04 black screen after succesful login on Virtual Box

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I get a black screen after login on ubuntu 18.04. I saw a lot of questions and "solutions" on the web but no one worked for me. By doing ctrl + alt + F2,

I tried:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y 
sudo reboot
```

and I also tried to reinstall ubuntu-desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

No one of this solution worked. I also tried to configure my VM by increase video memory. I also try solutions here: [ubuntu 18.04 Black screen after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068848/ubuntu-18-04-black-screen-after-login) .

I launch ubuntu on Virtual Box 6.1. My OS is Windows 10.

This problem seems to appear randomly. I install my VM. I work with it. I shutdown it. I re-work with it, I shutdown it. And then, black screen after login.

How can I fixed it?

EDIT

I already asked on stackoverflow, but I move the question here after some advices. I will close it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with 20.04 on virtual box 6.1 but it's not occasional, it occurs every time after login. It started this morning and affects 2 separate VMs - ubuntu 20.04 so I suspect it's an update on the host.

Until I find a real fix, there are 2 ways around that worked for me

1- change the display adapter from VMSVGA to VBoxSVGA in the VM settings
OR
2- at login, changed from X11 to Wayland (when you click on your name, there a "setting" icon that appears on the bottom right that lets you choose between "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu on Wayland", at least on 20.04)